# Reference a dict from another file in Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, lambda

I initially had an index.py file with contents like

```
import boto3
import json
import os
BUCKETNAME = os.environ['bucketname']
PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME = os.environ['publickkeysbucketname']
TRANSFERACCESSADMINROLE = os.environ['transferaccessadminrole']
TRANSFERACCESSREADROLE  = os.environ['transferaccessreadrole']
TRANSFERACCESSHUBADMINROLE = os.environ['transferaccesshubadminrole']
PRIMARY_REGION = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
SSM_PREFIX = os.environ['transferssmparameter']
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  auth_response = {}
  data_ret = {}
...
...
  data_pol = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
      "Sid": "AllowListAccessToBucket",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::" + BUCKETNAME, "arn:aws:s3:::" + PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME],
      "Condition": { "StringLike": { "s3:prefix": [ event["username"] + "/*",
                                                    event["username"]]}}},
      {"Sid": "GetAccessForPublicKeys",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectAcl","s3:GetObjectVersion","s3:GetBucketLocation"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::" + PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"]
          ,"arn:aws:s3:::" + PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"] + "/*"]},
      {"Sid": "PublicKeysPubFilePutAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:PutObject","s3:PutObjectAcl"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::" + PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"] + "/*.pub"]},
      {"Sid": "TransferDataBucketAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:PutObject","s3:PutObjectAcl","s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectAcl","s3:GetObjectVersion","s3:GetBucketLocation","s3:DeleteObject","s3:DeleteObjectVersion"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::" + BUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"],
          "arn:aws:s3:::" + BUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"] + "/*"]}]}

  data_ret["Policy"] = json.dumps(data_pol) ##### <---- Policy used here
  data_ret["HomeDirectoryType"] = "PATH"
  #data_ret["HomeDirectoryDetails"] = json.dumps(directorymapping)
  data_ret["HomeDirectory"] = "/" + BUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"]
  return data_ret
```

I want policies to be defined in another file. I added another file `policies.py` and its contents initially were

```
  data_pol = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
      "Sid": "AllowListAccessToBucket",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::" + BUCKETNAME, "arn:aws:s3:::" + PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME],
      "Condition": { "StringLike": { "s3:prefix": [ event["username"] + "/*",
                                                    event["username"]]}}},
      {"Sid": "GetAccessForPublicKeys",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectAcl","s3:GetObjectVersion","s3:GetBucketLocation"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::" + PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"]
          ,"arn:aws:s3:::" + PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"] + "/*"]},
      {"Sid": "PublicKeysPubFilePutAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:PutObject","s3:PutObjectAcl"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::" + PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"] + "/*.pub"]},
      {"Sid": "TransferDataBucketAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:PutObject","s3:PutObjectAcl","s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectAcl","s3:GetObjectVersion","s3:GetBucketLocation","s3:DeleteObject","s3:DeleteObjectVersion"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::" + BUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"],
          "arn:aws:s3:::" + BUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"] + "/*"]}]}
```

and i removed the policy declaration from `index.py`. I also added `import policies` to the top of `index.py`. I updated the call to the policy to

```
data_ret["Policy"] = json.dumps(policies.data_pol)
```

in `index.py`. This resulted in the error

```
  "errorMessage": "name 'BUCKETNAME' is not defined",
```

I then added the following to `policies.py`

```
import os

BUCKETNAME = os.environ['bucketname']
PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME = os.environ['publickkeysbucketname']
```

The next error was

```
  "errorMessage": "name 'event' is not defined",
```

`event` is the input to the lambda function.

So I added the `def lambda handler` and the full content of my `policies.py` file are now

```
import os

BUCKETNAME = os.environ['bucketname']
PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME = os.environ['publickkeysbucketname']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  data_pol = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
      "Sid": "AllowListAccessToBucket",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::" + BUCKETNAME, "arn:aws:s3:::" + PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME],
      "Condition": { "StringLike": { "s3:prefix": [ event["username"] + "/*",
                                                    event["username"]]}}},
      {"Sid": "GetAccessForPublicKeys",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectAcl","s3:GetObjectVersion","s3:GetBucketLocation"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::" + PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"]
          ,"arn:aws:s3:::" + PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"] + "/*"]},
      {"Sid": "PublicKeysPubFilePutAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:PutObject","s3:PutObjectAcl"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::" + PUBLICKEYSBUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"] + "/*.pub"]},
      {"Sid": "TransferDataBucketAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:PutObject","s3:PutObjectAcl","s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectAcl","s3:GetObjectVersion","s3:GetBucketLocation","s3:DeleteObject","s3:DeleteObjectVersion"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::" + BUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"],
          "arn:aws:s3:::" + BUCKETNAME + "/" + event["username"] + "/*"]}]}
```

And now the error message I get is

```
  "errorMessage": "'function' object has no attribute 'data_pols'",
```

What am i missing here ? All I want to do it to get `data_pol` defined in `policies.py` into `index.py`.

Comment: You mentioned that - "I also added import policies to the top of index.py". But that policies.py needs BUCKETNAME. But as you imported it on top and later defined - BUCKETNAME = os.environ['bucketname']. So you are getting - "errorMessage": "name 'BUCKETNAME' is not defined",

Comment: @SurajPandey Sorry I added the BUCKETNAME = os.environ['bucketname'] to policies.py. it was a mistake on my part. Ive corrected it. After adding that, the next error was regarding event

Comment: Can you try "import policies" after initializing all the global variables in index.py ?

Comment: your `lambda_handler` function in policies.py should return `data_pol` variable. Could you show us how you use `lambda_handler`? I suspect there is something like `lambda_handler.data_pol`

Answer (score 0):

in `policies.py` make `lambda_handler`(btw, consider giving it another name) returning dictionary(under variable `data_pol` in your case):

```
def build_policy(event, context):
    data_pol = { ... }
    return data_pol
```

In index.py, on top of the file:

```
from policies imports build_policy
```

Somewhere in your `index.py`(according to previous example how you wanna use it):

```
data_ret["Policy"] = json.dumps(build_policy(event, context))
```